# Draw order changes strangely as camera moves?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am currently developing a 3D gui system in libgdx, with the goal of making
a library useful for anyone who wants true 3d interfaces in their application. (that is, an interface constructed from model-instances)

This means in a lot of cases there will be transparent objects overlapping.

For example, a label object in a container. The label has a distance field shader (working nicely) and the container a outlined rectangle shader (working nicely). Both shaders have a transparent, or semi-transparent background.
The label is slightly in front of that container, and linked to its position/movements (also working nicely).

However, depending where the camera is positioned the labels background goes from correctly transparent, to masking out the background.
I assume this is some draw order issue?

Please see the video below to see how it relates to the camera motion;

http://youtu.be/3aADY3_vjV4 **(updated video - more clearly shows transparency's)**

(apologies for posting a video not a image, but I think it shows better how the problem changes based on movement)

I first move the camera around and you can see the order changing based on position. Seems to be about half way across the screen in changes.
I also turn the camera sideways a bit near the end so you can see the label (distance field shader) is above the containers (rectangle shader)

The materials both have a blend attribute set like this;

```
Material material = new Material(ICON_MATERIAL,
            new GlowingSquareShader.GlowingSquareAttribute(1f,DefaultColour,Color.WHITE),
            new BlendingAttribute(true,GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,1.0f));
```

My modelbatch is just using the default sort;

```
modelBatch = new ModelBatch(myshaderprovider);
```

(the sort this constructor then uses is;
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/DefaultRenderableSorter.java
- this isn't editable by me, but I can override and implement my own sort/compare if needed)

And my shaders setup the following in their begin methods;

```
context.setBlending(true,GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA ,GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
context.setDepthTest(GL20.GL_LESS);
```

Is this all correct?
What other areas could be going wrong?

Or is this an expected limitation of DefaultRenderableSorter.java? (that is, that transparent planes close together wont sort correctly)

Comment: To be clear, the problem you're having is the black background popping in front of the text? I see another issue here that has to do with the way you're depth sorting your labels. As the camera pans left/right, one label is drawn over top the other and this is probably because you're using a centroid sort (if this doesn't bother you, I'll ignore it :)).

Comment: Are you doing spherical billboarding or just aligning with the camera direction? That affects what method you should use for sorting. Also make sure the camera's near plane is significantly closer than the UI stuff and the far plane is at least a bit farther away.

Comment: They are simply aligned, no bill-boarding. The sorting method is LibGDX default which can be found here;
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/DefaultRenderableSorter.java

I'll check the near/far planes however.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman yes, the popping is my issue. I must confess I didnt even notice the other one. The sort method used is in the post above this, I'll edit it into the main text too.

Comment: Also, if people vote me down, can they say why in future? Have I not given enough details? Wrong section?

Comment: Dont set `BlendingAttribute#blended` to true for things that aren't blended (transparent).

Comment: They are both semi-transparent (hard to tell I guess at the moment as the background is flat and the res of my screen capture was quite low).

Comment: I am starting to think this is just a limitation of DefaultRenderableSorter, that I cant have transparent plans that close together?  If thats the case, given that the (relative) draw order of labels and containers is always known (that is, the label will always be infront of the container), is a viable solution to implement some sort of custom sorter with "z index" support?