# Optimal render draw-order function with specified z-index values

Tags: java, sorting, libgdx

I found recently the default renderable sort function in LibGDX wasn't quite up to my needs. (see; [Draw order changes strangely as camera moves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973600/draw-order-changes-strangely-as-camera-moves) )
Essentially a few objects rendered in front when they should render behind.

Fortunately, the renderables in question always have a guarantied relationship. The objects are attached to eachother so when one moves the other moves. One object can be seen as being literally "pinned" to the other, so always in front.

This gave me the idea that if I specified a "z-index" (int) and "groupname" (String) for each object, I could manually take over the draw order, and for things with the same groupname, ensure they are positioned next to eachother in the list, in the order specified by the z-index. (low to high)

```
 //For example an array of renderables like
 0."testgroup2",11
 1."testgroup",20
 2."testgroup2",10 
 3.(no zindex attribute)
 4."testgroup",50
 //Should sort to become
 0."testgroup",20
 1."testgroup",50
 2.(no zindex attribute)
 3."testgroup2",10
 4."testgroup2",11

 // assuming the object2 in testgroup2 are closer to the camera, the one without a index second closest, and the rest furthest<br>
 //(It is assumed that things within the same group wont be drastically different distances)
```

I implemented a sort system in libgdx to do this as followed;

```
/**
 * The goal of this sorter is to sort the renderables the same way LibGDX would do normally (in DefaultRenderableSorter)<br>
 * except if they have a ZIndex Attribute.<br>
 * A Zindex attribute provides a groupname string and a number.<br>
 * Renderables with the attribute are placed next to others of the same group, with the order within the group determined by the number<br>
 * 
 * For example an array of renderables like;<br><br>
 * 0."testgroup",20<br>
 * 1."testgroup2",10<br>
 * 2.(no zindex attribute)<br>
 * 3."testgroup",50<br>
 * <br>Should become;<br><br>
 * 0."testgroup",20<br>
 * 1."testgroup",50<br>
 * 2.(no zindex attribute)<br>
 * 3."testgroup2",10<br>
 * <br> 
 * assuming the object in testgroup2 is closer to the camera, the one without a index second closest, and the rest furthest<br>
 * (It is assumed that things within the same group wont be drastically different distances)<br>
 * 
 * @param camera - the camera in use to determine normal sort order when we cant place in a existing group
 * @param resultList - an array of renderables to change the order of
 */
private void customSorter(Camera camera, Array<Renderable> resultList) {

    //make a copy of the list to sort. (This is probably a bad start)
    Array <Renderable> renderables = new Array <Renderable> (resultList);

    //we work by clearing and rebuilding the Renderables array (probably not a good method)
    resultList.clear();

    //loop over the copy we made
    for (Renderable o1 : renderables) {

        //depending of if the Renderable as a ZIndexAttribute or not, we sort it differently
        //if it has one we do the following....
        if (o1.material.has(ZIndexAttribute.ID)){

            //get the index and index group name of it.
            int      o1Index   =  ((ZIndexAttribute)o1.material.get(ZIndexAttribute.ID)).zIndex;
            String o1GroupName =  ((ZIndexAttribute)o1.material.get(ZIndexAttribute.ID)).group;

            //setup some variables
            boolean placementFound = false; //Determines if a placement was found for this renderable (this happens if it comes across another with the same groupname)
            int defaultPosition = -1; //if it doesn't find another renderable with the same groupname, this will be its position in the list. Consider this the "natural" position based on distance from camera

            //start looping over all objects so far in the results (urg, told you this was probably not a good method)
            for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size; i++) {

                //first get the renderable and its ZIndexAttribute (null if none found)
                Renderable o2 = resultList.get(i);
                ZIndexAttribute o2szindex = ((ZIndexAttribute)o2.material.get(ZIndexAttribute.ID));

                if (o2szindex!=null){
                    //if the renderable we are comparing too has a zindex, then we get its information
                    int    o2index    = o2szindex.zIndex;
                    String o2groupname = o2szindex.group;       

                    //if its in the same group as o1, then we start the processing of placing them nexto eachother
                    if (o2groupname.equals(o1GroupName)){

                        //we either place it in front or behind based on zindex
                        if (o1Index<o2index){
                            //if lower z-index then behind it
                            resultList.insert(i, o1);
                            placementFound = true;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (o1Index>o2index){
                            //if higher z-index then it should go in front UNLESS there is another of this group already there too
                            //in which case we just continue (which will cause this to fire again on the next renderable in the inner loop)
                            if (resultList.size>(i+1)){

                                Renderable o3 = resultList.get(i+1);
                                ZIndexAttribute o3szindex = ((ZIndexAttribute)o3.material.get(ZIndexAttribute.ID));

                                if (o3szindex!=null){
                                    String o3groupname = o3szindex.group;   
                                    if (o3groupname!=null && o3groupname.equals(o1GroupName)){
                                        //the next element is also a renderable with the same groupname, so we loop and test that one instead   
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        //  Gdx.app.log("zindex", "__..placeing at:"+(i+1));
                            //else we place after the current one
                            resultList.insert(i+1, o1);
                            placementFound = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                }


                //if no matching groupname found we need to work out a default placement.
                int placement = normalcompare(o1, o2); //normal compare is the compare function in DefaultRenderableSorter. 

                if (placement>0){
                    //after then we skip
                    //(we are waiting till we are either under something or at the end

                } else {
                    //if placement is before, then we remember this position as the default (but keep looking as there still might be matching groupname, which should take priority)                                           
                    defaultPosition = i;
                    //break; //break out the loop
                }


            }

            //if we have checked all the renderables positioned in the results list, and none were found with matching groupname
            //then we use the defaultposition to insert it
            if (!placementFound){
                //Gdx.app.log("zindex", "__no placement found using default which is:"+defaultPosition);
                if (defaultPosition>-1){
                    resultList.insert(defaultPosition, o1);
                } else {
                    resultList.add(o1);
                }

            }

            continue;

        }

        //...(breath out)...
        //ok NOW we do placement for things that have no got a ZIndexSpecified
        boolean placementFound = false;

        //again, loop over all the elements in results
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size; i++) {

            Renderable o2 = resultList.get(i);

            //if not we compare by default to place before/after
            int placement = normalcompare(o1, o2);

            if (placement>0){
                //after then we skip
                //(we are waiting till we are either under something or at the end)
                continue;
            } else {
                //before                    
                resultList.insert(i, o1);
                placementFound = true;
                break; //break out the loop
            }


        }
        //if no placement found we go at the end by default
        if (!placementFound){
            resultList.add(o1);

        };


    } //go back to check the next element in the incomeing list of renderables (that is, the copy we made at the start)

    //done


}


//Copy of the default sorters compare function
//;
private Camera camera;
private final Vector3 tmpV1 = new Vector3();
private final Vector3 tmpV2 = new Vector3();

public int normalcompare (final Renderable o1, final Renderable o2) {
    final boolean b1 = o1.material.has(BlendingAttribute.Type) && ((BlendingAttribute)o1.material.get(BlendingAttribute.Type)).blended;
    final boolean b2 = o2.material.has(BlendingAttribute.Type) && ((BlendingAttribute)o2.material.get(BlendingAttribute.Type)).blended;
    if (b1 != b2) return b1 ? 1 : -1;
    // FIXME implement better sorting algorithm
    // final boolean same = o1.shader == o2.shader && o1.mesh == o2.mesh && (o1.lights == null) == (o2.lights == null) &&
    // o1.material.equals(o2.material);
    o1.worldTransform.getTranslation(tmpV1);
    o2.worldTransform.getTranslation(tmpV2);
    final float dst = (int)(1000f * camera.position.dst2(tmpV1)) - (int)(1000f * camera.position.dst2(tmpV2));
    final int result = dst < 0 ? -1 : (dst > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    return b1 ? -result : result;
}
```

As far as I can tell my customSorter function produces the order I want - the renderables now look like they are drawn in the right order.

However, this also seems like a hackjob, and I am sure my sorting algorithm is horrendously inefficient.

**I would like advice on how to either;**

a) Improve my own algorithm, especially in regards to any quirks to bare in mind when doing cross-platform LibGDX development (ie, array types, memory management in regards to android/web etc)

b) Alternative more efficient solutions having a similar "z index override" of the normal draw-order sorting.

Notes;
 . The grouping is necessary. This is because while things are firmly stuck relatively to eachother within a group, groups themselves can also move about in front/behind eachother. (but not between). This makes it tricky to do a "global" override of the draw order, rather then a local one per group.

. If it helps, I can add/change the zindexattribute object in any way.

. I am thinking somehow "pre-storeing" each group of objects in a array could help things, but not 100% sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do never copy a list if not needed. The list with renderables could be really huge since it also could contain resources. Copying will be very very slow. If you need something local and you need performance try to make it final since it can improve the performance.

So a simple approach would be the default sorting of Java. You need to implement a Comperator for your class for example the Class with z index could look like this:

```
public class MyRenderable {
    private float z_index;
    public MyRenderable(float i)
    {
        z_index = i;
    }

    public float getZ_index() {
        return z_index;
    }

    public void setZ_index(float z_index) {
        this.z_index = z_index;
    }
}
```

If you want a faster sort since your list wont change that much on runtime you could implement a insertion sort since it does a faster job if the list is kind of presorted. If it is not pre sorted it does take longer but in general it should only be the first sort call where it is alot disordered in your case.

```
private void sortList(ArrayList<MyRenderable> array) {
    // double starttime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
        final MyRenderable temp = array.get(i);
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && array.get(j).getZ_index() < temp.getZ_index()) {
            array.set(j + 1, array.get(j));
            j--;
        }
        array.set(j + 1, temp);
    }
    // System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.nanoTime() - starttime));
}
```

To use this method you simply call it with your Array

```
sortList(renderbales);
```

In your case you need to take care of the ones that do not have a Z index. Maybe you could give them a 0 since they'll get sorted at the right position(i guess). Else you can use the given methods in z case and the regular in no z case as you do already.

---

After the conversation in the comments. I dont think it is a good idea to push everything into **one** list. It's hard to sort and would be very slow. A better approach would be a list of groups. Since you want to have groups, programm a group. Do not use String names, use IDs or types (way more easy to sort and it doesn't really matter). So a simple group would be this:

```
public class Group{
//think about privates and getters or methods to add things which also checks some conditions and so on
    public int groupType; 
    public ArrayList<MyRenderable> renderables;
}
```

And now all your groups into a list. (this contains all your renderbales then)

```
ArrayList<Group> allRenderables = new ArrayList<>();
```

Last but not least sort the groups and sort the renderables. Since i dont think that your group ids/names will change on runtime, sort them once or even use a SortedSet instead of a ArrayList. But basically the whole sorting looks like this:

```
    for(Group g: allRenderables)
        sortRenderables(g.renderables); //now every group is sorted
    //now sort by group names
    sortGroup(allRenderables);
```

With the following insertionsorts as shown above

```
public static void sortRenderables(ArrayList<MyRenderable> array) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
        final MyRenderable temp = array.get(i);
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && array.get(j).getZ_index() < temp.getZ_index()) {
            array.set(j + 1, array.get(j));
            j--;
        }
        array.set(j + 1, temp);
    }
}

public static void sortGroup(ArrayList<Group> array) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
        final Group temp = array.get(i);
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && array.get(j).groupType < temp.groupType) {
            array.set(j + 1, array.get(j));
            j--;
        }
        array.set(j + 1, temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not so simple. If you can take a look at the question again, theres a grouping requirement that seems to complicate things quite a bit beyond a simple Collections/compare solution. (or at least seems to for me).
Your insertion sort recommendation might still be valid in principle, however, seeing as the list shouldn't change frequently.

Comment: One second ill make a approach

Comment: Sorry for my slow response, but now I have time to look that solution it seems superb. Spliting the groups of lets me only sort whats required rather then the whole lot, and the "per frame" sort based on camera updates now is mostly sorting pre-sorted groups thus drastically reducing the work.
Excellent!